# How can I use the function sscanf to read specific characters?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read the information from the file and give the value of `a` in file to the "a" and value of `b` to the "b". But it didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    char zahla[128];
    char zahlb[128];
    char zimu[128];

    fp = fopen("./0312.conf", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("error");
        return (-1);
    }
    while (fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
        sscanf(buffer, "%^", zimu);
        printf("zimu is: %s\n", zimu);

        if (strcmp(zimu, "a") == 0) {
            sscanf(buffer, "%[1-9]s", zahla);
        }
        if (strcmp(zimu, "b") == 0) {
            sscanf(buffer, "%[1-9]s", zahlb);
        }
    }
    printf("a=%s, b=%s\n", zahla, zahlb);
}
```

the content of the file is:

```
       a=10
                b=5
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear, sorry.

Comment: Indented by 4-spaces so the code and data is proper formatted as fixed-width.

Comment: You are looking for a simple parser. You should read the file into a buffer and use for example `char *ptr = strstr(buf, "a="); int zahla = atoi(ptr+2);` (and similar for b). Of course you have to do error checking and perhaps some more advanced parsing: Bottom line: `sscanf()` seems inappropriate for your task at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The format specifier `"%^"` is meaningless and won't actually do anything -- so you never get anything in your `zimu` array.
- The `s` after `%[1-9]` in a format specifier means "match a literal 's' character", so will never match.  You probably just want to remove it.
- Since your input lines start with `a=` or `b=`, the `"%[1-9]"` format specifiers will not match.

Most likely what you want is something like

```
char name[100], value[100];
if (sscanf(buffer, " %99[a-z] = %99[0-9]", name, value) == 2) {
    // matched a line with name=value, do something with it
} else {
    // didn't match -- give an error?
}
```

- use space characters in the format to skip whitespace -- whenever there is a space it will skip over 0 or more whitespace characters.  Note the 0 -- a space is not required, and any number of spaces may be there
- ALWAYS check the return value to see if the expected number of items matched
- You need something in the format to match all the characters on the line, though format specifiers other than `%[` and `%c` will also skip whitespace, and you can ignore trailing stuff if you don't care about it.  If you do care about trailing stuff, you can use `%n` to check how many characters you scanned to make sure it is the entire line.
- use bounds on `%s` and `%[` specifiers reading into fixed arrays to ensure that they don't overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion regarding the `%[abc]` scansets in `scanf` format strings: you should specify the maximum number of characters to read and give the character ranges between the `[` and `]`. There is no trailing `s` after the `]`. Extra spaces in the format string cause spaces to be skipped.

Here is a corrected version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    char zimu[128];
    char zahla[128];
    char zahlb[128];

    fp = fopen("./0312.conf", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("error");
        return -1;
    }
    zahla[0] = zahlb[0] = '\0';
    while (fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(buffer, " %127[a-z]", zimu) != 1)
            continue;
        printf("zimu is: %s\n", zimu);
        if (strcmp(zimu, "a") == 0) {
            sscanf(buffer, " a = %127[1-9]", zahla);
        }
        if (strcmp(zimu, "b") == 0) {
            sscanf(buffer, " b = %127[1-9]", zahlb);
        }
    }
    printf("a=%s, b=%s\n", zahla, zahlb);
    return 0;
}
```