# how to use scanf to read specific characters?

Tags: c

I need to read specific charters from terminal, How can I do this? I need reading this characters `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`. Is there any way to do this using `scanf`?

I tried `scanf("%[(,),[,]]s", string)`, but it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the function sscanf to read specific characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148326/how-can-i-use-the-function-sscanf-to-read-specific-characters)

Comment: What do you mean?  If the next character on the input stream is `a`, do you want to magically not read it?  You won't be able to tell what the character is until you read it.  The only choice you can make is what you do with it after you read it.

Comment: What do you mean by "read specific characters"? Read any string composed of those characters? Read those characters in a specific order? Read input delimited by those characters? Give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `]` first in the list of characters to match so that it is not taken as terminating the conversion specifier.  Also, unless you want to match commas, don't include them.  And unless you want to match a literal `s`, don't put the `s` in the format string.  The conversion specifier ends with `]`.   I think you're just looking for something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char buf[32];
        if( scanf("%31[][(){}]", buf) == 1 ) {
                printf(" read: '%s'\n", buf);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` conversion specifier for a character class should start with `]` if it must contain this character and it does not have a trailing `s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[2];        

    while (scanf("%1[][(){}]", str) == 1) {
        printf("got %c\n", str[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```